# Files are not shown on mounted partition that is booted from LiveCd

Tags: mount, elementary, uuid

I need help. I have installed Arch after Ubuntu and Elementary OS, and after that my grub was messed up, and I was unable to boot again in Elementary OS. So I decided to backup my files from home partition and to reinstall it.

I used BootRepair LiveCD, mounted /dev/sda3 (elementary partition) but than when I enter /mnt/home/$USER/ I see only directories, not files!

There are Desktop, Documents.. etc.. but when I enter those folders, it shows no files. I've tried ls -al, and many other options, tried to copy recursively folder on some other location, but it would copy only directoryes.

I've read a litle, that you have to sync UID between two OS to be able to access all files, but I don't know how to do it.. Or is there some other way?

Can anyone help?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases **so elementary is off-topic here as well.** However, on http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at elementary, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**